# make jquery ajax calls to asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

How do I go about making true ajax requests to an asp.net page? (Not update panels). I read this tutorial but couldn't get it working. Is there a better approach? Or should this work?

http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What do you have so far? No, it's the best approach. Yes, it should work.

Comment: @negative that was rather positive ;) ~ @nick you should really really share some code that you've tried or illustrate what's not working for you so we know what your level of understanding is.

Comment: I understand the concept of using jquery, I just didnt know how the rest works, like do you mark your methods with webrequest. Just trying to see what techniques are available. I am new to Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard today is using JSON to get the job done. That means you'll be using JavaScript, and when you're using JavaScript jQuery is your friend.

Here's some [example code](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/96/Handling-JSON-Arrays-returned-from-ASP.NET-Web-Services-with-jQuery) that uses AJAX, jQuery, and a .NET Web Service. Learn it, love it, live it.

Answer (score 0):

Try PageMethods. It will be easier. You're living in a .NET world, use the .NET tools.

Here's a page to get you started.

http://aspalliance.com/1922